# Vanilla JS How Parse json into html

Tags: javascript, json

I Have a url json file containing a product information:
img, url, title, etc...

I'd like to display the datas on my carousel that is already fully in place.
What's the best way? I'm really struggling with the itemsData.

What am I missing?

possibly id like to display the datas on the right tags?
Any help much appreciated
Have a fiddle demo below, I hope someone can drive me through the solution.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
      <ul id="carousel">
      </ul>
</div>
```

**JSON**

```
    "itemsData": [{
    {
    "productUrl": "hdhdhdhdh.html",
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "productTitle": "sksksksksk",
    "price": "8383838"
    }
]
```

**JS**

```
 const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'myJson.json');
request.responseText = 'json';
 
request.onload = function () {
  // Convert JSON data to an object 
  let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 

  let output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    output += '<li class="carousel-seat"><h4>' + data[i].productTitle + '</h4> <p>Price ' + data[i].price + ' </p></li>'
  }
  document.getElementById('carousel').innerHTML = output;
}
request.send();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davidesitua/m1y469db/

Comment: btw from ur fiddle im just getting `Script Error.`

Comment: yes, the json is not there Is just an example

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rcah3g8x/1/
What is the problem I can't understand.

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist on my local I have webpack solution but I can't get the json working? my json file is in the same forder of the js file. On fiddle works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` doesn't have a length(it is not the array)

However `data.itemsData` is an array(therefore it has a length)

I have an example further down, however for your actual javascript, it would be something like

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'myJson.json');
request.responseText = 'json';
 
request.onload = function () {
  // Convert JSON data to an object 
  let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  let dataa=data.itemsData
  let output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) {
    output += '<li class="carousel-seat"><h4>' + dataa[i].productTitle + '</h4> <p>Price ' + dataa[i].price + ' </p></li>'
  }
  document.getElementById('carousel').innerHTML = output;
}
request.send();
```

```js
let data =  
{
  "itemsData": 
  [
    {
    "productUrl": "hdhdhdhdh.html",
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "productTitle": "sksksksksk",
    "price": "8383838"
    }
  ]
}

var dataa=data.itemsData
var output=''
for (var i = 0; i < dataa.length; i++) {
  output += '<li class="carousel-seat"><h4>' + dataa[i].productTitle + '</h4> <p>Price ' + dataa[i].price + ' </p></li>'
}
document.getElementById('carousel').innerHTML=output
```

```html
<div id="carousel"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know why on my webpack I can't get the json working? my json file is in the same forder of the js file.

Comment: @user173420 would changing the `request.open` line to `request.open('GET', location.href+'myJson.json')` help?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your JSON is wrong.

```
 "itemsData": [{
    {
    "productUrl": "hdhdhdhdh.html",
    "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
    "productTitle": "sksksksksk",
    "price": "8383838"
    }
]
```

This is **wrong** JSON

Correct JSON will be like this.

```
{
  "itemsData": [
    {
      "productUrl": "test.html",
      "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
      "productTitle": "Test",
      "price": "8383838"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your **"itemsData"** is an array, so you need to have `data.itemsData[i]` to access the inner object of the JSON.

Thus `data.itemsData.length` will give you the items you have in an array.

Check below code:

```js
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/6023c6b7435c323ba1c44646/1');
request.responseText = 'json';

request.onload = function() {
  // Convert JSON data to an object 
  let data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

  let output = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.itemsData.length; i++) {
    output += '<li class="carousel-seat"><h4>Title: ' + data.itemsData[i].productTitle + '</h4> <p>Price ' + data.itemsData[i].price + ' </p></li>'
  }
  document.getElementById('carousel').innerHTML = output;



}
request.send();
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <ul id="carousel">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the "onreadystatechange" method:

```
    function readJson(jsonFile, callback) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", jsonFile, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status == "200") {
            callback(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send(null);
}
```

Then use the function as you want like this:

```
readJson("json.json", function(text){
    var data = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log(data);
});
```

On the other hand, your Json file is wrong written:

```
{
"itemsData": [
  {
  "productUrl": "hdhdhdhdh.html",
  "imageSrc": "image.jpg",
  "productTitle": "sksksksksk",
  "price": "8383838"
    }
]
}
```